# split & reorder strings function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create function in sql server to split string   
delimiter by space and reorder them 
name reFormat(myinput)
while myinput is mycolumn name
**note:**
" [ ] " should be removed and "-" should be connect the new output instead of space with the new order(moving the third group to the begining) 
example:
myinput:    [1A] 1B 1C 1D 
output:    1C_1A_1B_1D

select myinput from mytable
[1A] 1B 1C 1D 

select reFormat(myinput) from mytable
1C_1A_1B_1D

Comment: What's the significance of `[]` and `_`? Are you just using them to attempt to highlight something (what?) or are they actually part of the data? If part of the data, why aren't they mentioned in your problem description? Why, specifically, is the `1C` element moved to the front? Because it's the third group? Or the last-but-one? Or some other rule that you've not articulated?

Comment: How does `1A` come after `1C` but before `1B`?

Comment: Because I want to Reorder groups >>>> only the third one moved infront ... the rest in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[reFormat]
(
    @inText varchar(max)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outText VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE @node VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @node3 VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @count INT;
    SET @count = 1;
    DECLARE @space CHAR(1) = '_'

    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @inText) > 0
     BEGIN
      SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(' ', @inText)
      SELECT @node = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@inText, 1, @pos-1), '[',''), ']','');


      IF @count = 3
        BEGIN
            SET @node3 = @node;
        END    
      ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @outText = CONCAT(@outText, @space + @node);
        END    
      SET @count = @count + 1;

      SELECT @inText = SUBSTRING(@inText, @pos+1, LEN(@inText)-@pos)
     END
     SELECT @node = REPLACE(REPLACE(@inText, '[',''), ']',''); 
     SET @outText = CONCAT(@node3, @outText) + @space + @node;

    RETURN @outText;

END
```

And the code which used it:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable 
(myinput varchar(255));
INSERT INTO #MyTable ( myinput ) VALUES  ( '[1A] 1B 1C 1D');

select dbo.reFormat(myinput) from #MyTable

DROP TABLE #MyTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what am look for

Answer (score 0):

```
select @var = @var+data+'_' from (SELECT TOP 1 data
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
               OVER (
                 ORDER BY data) id,
          data
       FROM   (SELECT Replace(Replace(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), '[', ''), ']', '') data
               FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                                    + Replace('[1A] 1B 1C 1D', ' ', '</M><M>')
                                    + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                      CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) b) c
WHERE  id = 3
UNION all
SELECT data
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  ORDER BY data) id,
              data
       FROM   (SELECT Replace(Replace(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), '[', ''), ']', '') data
               FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                                    + Replace('[1A] 1B 1C 1D', ' ', '</M><M>')
                                    + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                      CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) b) c
WHERE  id != 3 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@var , 1, LEN(@var)-1)
```